# Python AND JSON Parsing

Tags: python, json

I am new to python or JSON. I have a file that has JSON data.

When I tried to read the file file. "Items" is the key of the file. I used following python script:

```
data=pandas.read_json('fileName.json') #using pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame(data) or json.loads #-> to read the file
print df.get('Items', {}) #-> to read entire file 
print df['Items'][0]['Patron'] #-> I can read an individual Patron like at '0' or '100'. But I want to generate the list of all 'patron' from the list. How do I do that? Any advise?
```

If I do remove [0] I get Key error or something. I am sure its because of unable to access the dictionary. Is there any way to resolve it?

```
{"Items": [{
  "Activity": "search.api",
  "Library": 1531,
  "Patron": 583586,
  "Tag": "browse-eaudio-religion",
  "Items": [
    "mediatype:eaudio",
    "genre:religion",
    "libraryid:1531",
    "ownership:owned",
    "usertype:patron",
    "page-count:5",
    "page-index:0",
    "page-size:60",
    "resultset-count:290",
    "sort:"
  ],
  "SearchType": "browse",
  "MediaType": "eaudio",
  "Genre": "religion",
  "NamedQuery": null,
  "Input": null,
  "ResultsetCount": 290,
  "Year": 2015,
  "Month": 4,
  "Day": 0,
  "Hour": 13
},{
  "Activity": "search.api",
  "Library": 985,
  "Patron": 674919,
  "Tag": "quick-author",
  "Items": [
    "libraryid:985",
    "ownership:owned",
    "usertype:patron",
    "page-count:93",
    "page-index:0",
    "page-size:60",
    "resultset-count:5552",
    "sort:author"
  ],
  "SearchType": null,
  "MediaType": "",
  "Genre": "",
  "NamedQuery": null,
  "Input": null,
  "ResultsetCount": 5552,
  "Year": 2015,
  "Month": 4,
  "Day": 0,
  "Hour": 13
}
```

Comment: Khelweed3- Klaus's answer below solves the issue. Thank you for the time

Comment: why using pandas but not the build-in `json` module?

Comment: P.R.10- I actually tried both. Using Pandas just do ease my statistical analysis :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
patron_list = [item.get('Patron') for item in df['Items']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# this is your data, simplified a bit,
# and indented for better readability:
data = {
    "Items": [
        {
          "Activity": "search.api",
          "Library": 1531,
          "Patron": 583586,
          "Tag": "browse-eaudio-religion",
        },
        {
          "Activity": "search.api",
          "Library": 985,
          "Patron": 674919,
          "Tag": "quick-author",
        }
    ]
}

# so you want 'Patron' field from every element in list data['Items']

# you can use list comprehension for this:
patrons = [item['Patron'] for item in data['Items']]

print patrons
# output:
# [583586, 674919]
```